# My API PUT will not work

Tags: javascript, json, api

I cannot get ajax to do a 'PUT' operation.

```js
$('.thetest').click(function() {
  console.log("Script executed");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'redacted for obvious reasons',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
      alert("success?");
    },
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {
      "userId": "also redacted",
      "data": {
        "userSettings": {
          "notificationSettings": {
            "Marketing": false,
            "Newsletters": true

          }

        }
      }
    },

  });

});
```

```html
<button class="thetest"> PRESS ME</button>
```

Once the button is pressed, the console.log does trigger. So I know the script is being used, it just doesn't send to the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: The console.log inside the "click" function doesn't mean that the AJAX works. Your back-end (API) is localhost?

Comment: check the network tab in chrome dev tools if the request is going out but maybe just failing?]

Comment: @LiefdeWen Cheers, i got 400 bad request. What could this be? or is that far too broad to accurately pin point

Comment: @LewisClarke If it's a 400 code, it mean's it definitely reached a webserver but the webserver return with that error code. That's why your alert isn't firing, if you put the error handler in your code you will see that that method will fire

Answer (score -1):

change type to method

```
 $('.thetest').click(function () {
            console.log("Script executed");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'redacted for obvious reasons',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success?");
                },
                method: 'PUT',
                data: {
                    "userId": "also redacted",
                    "data": {
                        "userSettings": {
                            "notificationSettings": {
                                "Marketing": false,
                                "Newsletters": true

                            }

                        }
                    }
                },

            });

        });
```

Comment: This won't make any difference. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). `type` is an alias for `method`.